# What's the best way to create RFC-4180-friendly CSV files from Amazon Redshift UNLOAD?

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

Amazon Redshift doesn't really have a CSV option when using `UNLOAD` (e.g., similar to the `WITH CSV` available in PostgreSQL's `COPY` command).

If you use the `ESCAPE` option, Redshift escapes double quotes with a `\`. Excel, for example, doesn't know what to do with that slash. It should really be using a double quote, per RFC-4180

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>   appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>   another double quote.  For example:
>
> `"aaa","b""bb","ccc"`

Sooo... quotes are going to break exports unless we can figure out a way to make Redshift escape them properly.

Given the following data:

```
# select * from unload_test;
                 test_field                 | test_field_number
 --------------------------------------------+-------------------
 "No," she said, "that's not how we do it." |                 5
 Hi! This is a test, yo.                    |                 5
```

- If we use `ESCAPE` but no `ADDQUOTES`, Excel et al continues to break columns on all commas including the "escaped" ones (`\,`). [Example](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2156/12654433/91f2ae2a-c5b9-11e5-83a6-0e2ad3977a5e.png)
- If we use both `ESCAPE` and `ADDQUOTES` you get the result you see in the initial issue example.
- If we use `ADDQUOTES` but we don't use `ESCAPE` then it will break on double-quotes in the data. [Example](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2156/12654501/de753ae2-c5b9-11e5-89ab-e1cac6f74aac.png)
- Of course, if we don't use either then we'll also break on commas and possible quotes.

Is there an available work-around for this that will accommodate both quotes and commas in the data?

Comment: From the documentation it also does not seem smart enough to only add quotes when quotes are needed.

Comment: In a perfect world, you'd add a `RFC4180` clause and it would just start obeying the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling solution was to process contents using perl / sed and convert it to proper CSV.

These flags are required: `DELIMITER ',' ADDQUOTES ESCAPE`.

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/non_csv/part_0000 - | \
# Unescapes \" into "" but only when odd number of backslashes are found backwards
perl -pe 's/((?<![\\])(\\\\)*)\\"/\1""/g' | \
# Removes \ but only when odd number of backslashes are found backwards
perl -pe 's/((?<![\\])(\\\\)*)\\/\1/g' | \
# Unescapes \\ into \
sed -e 's/\\\\/\\/g' | \
aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/csv/part_0000
```

I tested this using various edge cases on a real noisy data and it produces correct results. All backslashes are removed because nothing must be escaped except `"` -> `""` and added quoting.

Example test:

```
$ echo '"","\"\"Hi\\\\\"","\\\\","\<tab>"' | perl -pe 's/((?<![\\])(\\\\)*)\\"/\1""/g' | perl -pe 's/((?<![\\])(\\\\)*)\\/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\\\\/\\/g'
```

Output:

```
"","""""Hi\\""","\\","<tab>"
```

PERL or other advanced regexp engine is required to do a correct look-behind.

Performance was not an issue, because I hit network bandwidth instead of CPU. However, one can use GNU parallel to process all output files at once.

However, I did not test `aws s3 cp` part, because I use another tool to get S3 contents into STDIN.

Cheers!